# How to trigger "Get Info" for file using command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

Similarly to running `open "/Applications/Firefox.app"`, I would like to open the "Get Info" window of `/Applications/Firefox.app` using command line.

Comment: Can you explain your broader workflow? Why do you need to get info from a shell command? Do you need the actual data, or just the window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with a shell command, but you can use a shell script to run AppleScript, which can do it. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24421803/open-info-window-in-finder-by-applescript

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37231942/open-get-information-window-in-finder-by-applescript-again

For example:

```sh
osascript -e "set aFile to (POSIX file \"/Applications/Firefox.app\") as text" \
          -e "tell application \"Finder\" to open information window of file aFile"
```

If you want to add in your bash or zsh profile:

```bsh
getfileinfo() {
  local FILE="$1"

  if [[ -r "${FILE}" ]]; then
    osascript <<EOF
set aFile to (POSIX file "$FILE") as alias
tell application "Finder" to open information window of aFile
EOF
  fi
}
```

Comment: Brilliant indeed, so you can just add something like: `osascript <<EOF
set aFile to (POSIX file "$FILE") as alias
tell application "Finder" to open information window of aFile
EOF` in your dotfiles

Comment: @RakibFiha I've changed the condition in the `if`, `-f` is always false for applications.

Comment: @RakibFiha `-f` basically tests for existance of a *file*, things like `Firefox.app` are always directories. Using `-r` works, as would `-e`.