# Open info panel from command line

Tags: terminal, finder, command-line, icon

The `open` command does the equivalent of double-clicking a file or directory but is there a command to do the equivalent of right-click > Get Info?

GetFileInfo outputs info to the terminal, I want to open the info panel window on the desktop.

Alternatively, if there's a command-line way to set an app's icon, rather than dropping the new icon on the app's info panel, that would be great.

Comment: This seems to be asking two things at once, can you please focus the question on one problem only?

Comment: For your first question, see: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410743/how-to-trigger-get-info-for-file-using-command-line

Comment: @nohillside, sorry for the two things.  I thought it might be useful to say _why_ I want to open the info panel.

Comment: If you plan to do the second step manually/via mouse, it doesn’t seem to be relevant for the question. If, OTOH, you want to change the icon from the command line, please ask this :-)